# Unable to specify separate link in the google plus icon

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus

i am using google plus icon in my site using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
 <g:plusone size="medium" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/104806777345217966807/"></g:plusone>
```

but whenever i click that button it redirect me into wrong URL . How to i change this

```
> https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=oz&continue=https://plusone.google.com/%2B1/profile/?type%3Dpo%26client%3D1%26gpsrc%3Dwidget%26parent%3Dhttps://plusone.google.com%26proxy%3DI2_1334919708352%26rsz%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26gpsrc%3Dwidget&hl=en-US#724922462
```

If i use the below code it redirect me to given path but it show different view

Please guide me i already searched in all blog but i did not get solution for my issue

Comment: Anyone who clicks the +1 button will be directed to the Google+ login page, unless they are already logged in. If they are logged in, they will +1 the page.

Comment: yes i understand that . If you click this link also it redirect the user to google login page "https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/104806777345217966807/" but this page has different look

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the *+1* button is for the viewer to plus 1, or recommend the linked site publicly on *Google+*

So the person has to be logged into G+ to be able to do it and thus the link redirects you to the google login page.

If I understand you correctly, you want an G+ image link to that page. In this case simply find and add a G+ icon image and enclose it within `<a />` tag pointing to the link.

Comment: please sea my edited code i need same functionality of <g:plus href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/104806777345217966807/"
                width='170' height='69'></g:plus> in <g:plusone></g:plusone>